# Database is not closed error altough closed in code

Tags: android, sql

I am having a issue where I am strugling with for a few days now. It keeps giving me an **error that my databased wasn't closed**. I get items out of my sql db and put them in a gridview with a custom adapter. If you click on an item, it will take you to another class (answer.java). Doing nothing and hitting the back button won't cause an error, but if I call a certain function and hit the back button after this function, I get the close() error **when pressing the back button**.
So this is the exact error:

```
    11-19 19:56:22.485: E/Database(7403): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.test.game/databases/quizDb' 
11-19 19:56:22.485: E/Database(7403): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
11-19 19:56:22.485: E/Database(7403):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1847)
11-19 19:56:22.485: E/Database(7403):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
11-19 19:56:22.485: E/Database(7403):   at com.test.game.db.DataBaseHelper.openDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:117)
11-19 19:56:22.485: E/Database(7403):   at com.test.game.Answer.loadDataBase(Answer.java:179)
11-19 19:56:22.485: E/Database(7403):   at com.test.game.Answer.onClick(Answer.java:240)
11-19 19:56:22.485: E/Database(7403):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2491)
11-19 19:56:22.485: E/Database(7403):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9086)
11-19 19:56:22.485: E/Database(7403):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-19 19:56:22.485: E/Database(7403):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-19 19:56:22.485: E/Database(7403):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-19 19:56:22.485: E/Database(7403):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-19 19:56:22.485: E/Database(7403):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 19:56:22.485: E/Database(7403):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-19 19:56:22.485: E/Database(7403):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:861)
11-19 19:56:22.485: E/Database(7403):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:619)
11-19 19:56:22.485: E/Database(7403):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think I found the part of the code which is causing this error, if I don't call myDbHelper.insertString(...) in my answer.java file anymore, I don't get the error anymore...

```
public void insertString(int id, int level, String field, String player) {

    Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM ANSWERS WHERE QUESTION_ID=" + id
                    + " AND PLAYER ='" + player + "'", null);

    myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();

    if (c != null) {
        myDataBase.execSQL("UPDATE ANSWERS SET " + field + "=1"
                + " WHERE QUESTION_ID=" + id + " AND LEVEL =" + level
                + " AND PLAYER='" + player + "'");
    } else {
        myDataBase
                .execSQL("INSERT INTO ANSWERS (level, player, question_id, "
                        + field + ") VALUES ("+ level + ",'" + player + "'," + id + ", 1)");
    }

    c.close();
    if (myDataBase != null) {
        myDataBase.close();

    }

}
```

One of the things I tried but didn't solve it was adding this to my answer.java file:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if (myDbHelper != null) {
                 myDbHelper.close();
            }
return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

// and .close() in my databasehelper.java is:

```
@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    if (c != null)
        c.close();
    super.close();
}
```

Hope somebody can show me the light!

EDIT

@sam your solution gives me this:

```
11-19 19:52:42.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6982): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 19:52:42.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6982): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: attempt to write a readonly database: UPDATE ANSWERS SET showhint1=1 WHERE QUESTION_ID=18 AND LEVEL =1 AND PLAYER='trst'
11-19 19:52:42.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6982):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
11-19 19:52:42.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6982):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1763)
11-19 19:52:42.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6982):     at com.test.game.db.DataBaseHelper.insertString(DataBaseHelper.java:301)
11-19 19:52:42.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6982):     at com.test.game.Answer.onClick(Answer.java:241)
11-19 19:52:42.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6982):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2491)
11-19 19:52:42.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6982):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9086)
11-19 19:52:42.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6982):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-19 19:52:42.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6982):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-19 19:52:42.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6982):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-19 19:52:42.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6982):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-19 19:52:42.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6982):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 19:52:42.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6982):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-19 19:52:42.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6982):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:861)
11-19 19:52:42.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6982):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:619)
11-19 19:52:42.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6982):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `com.test.game.Answer.onClick(Answer.java:249)` is where you open but not close the database

Comment: Does it matter? I close it in my databasehelper.java file.. I don't think it matters where you close it? but even then, as I said, if I close it in my onkeyDown method, it still gives me the error...

Comment: PS:  if I put myDbHelper.close(); right behind calling the insertstring method in my answer.java file I still have the error.. so I don't think that this is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM ANSWERS WHERE QUESTION_ID=" + id
                + " AND PLAYER ='" + player + "'", null);

//Try adding this
myDatabase.close();

myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Edit: try making the change as below:

```
myDatabase.close();
myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM ANSWERS WHERE QUESTION_ID=" + id
                + " AND PLAYER ='" + player + "'", null);

//move this to before the rawQuery
//myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: Well, I don't get the error anymore.. but it also doesn't insert the value to my db now... I guess it closes the c cursor as well, tries to update which doesnt work and that that is causing the fact that it doesnt insert it to my db.. would this be possible?

Comment: How about simply calling `myDataBase.close()` then `myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();` and only then fetching the Cursor with `rawQuery()`? (Understand this doesn't address the real problem, it is only a band-aid.)

Comment: What Sam mentioned is the real problem i guess. There is an instance of database already open. You need to close that before opening another instance.

Comment: Well I am very happy because I don't get the close() error anymore! But it doesn't insert the values to my DB now... very strange.. any ideas on that ? :s

Comment: For those who wonder: it didn't insert with if (c!=null) but it does work with if (c.moveToFirst) { :)

Answer (score 2):

Clearly you open your database in more than one location:

```
// myDataBase is already open or else this could not work
Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM ANSWERS WHERE QUESTION_ID=" + id
                + " AND PLAYER ='" + player + "'", null);

// You are opening myDataBase again
myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Simply go through your code looking for `getWritableDatabase()` and `getReadableDatabase()` finding any location where you have forgotten to close it. *Or* if you access the database a lot, open the database once in your Activity's `onResume()` and close it once in `onPause()`.

Comment: But I do close the c cursor and the myDataBase in the same method? So isn't this correctly closed then?

Comment: Well, I can't quite guess what is happening elsewhere in your code... But what happens when you comment out `myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();`?

Comment: I extend the SQLiteOpenHelper class, I didn't code this method myself http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase()

Comment: Hmm, did you try my suggestion? And I know Android's SQLiteOpenHelper class, it's open source. But I don't have access to _your_ DataBaseHelper or _your_ Activities... Also post all of your LogCat errors, so we can see what is really happening.

Comment: Thanks, but how and where else do you access the database in your Answer Activity?

Comment: At different points.. the errors are gone now (used solution above) but now it doesn't insert it into my db..

Comment: Simply close the database every time you open it. Don't avoid the problem by using a band-aid, this makes it worse. (I cannot help you beyond this without seeing a lot more code. The choice is yours.)

Comment: Ok Sam, since I rather don't want to put everything up here I will check closely every statement, but for now, it seems that it thinks that c = not null and it just skips the insert statement...

Comment: just as info, is it good enough to close it in my databasehelper.java? Because I load the database in my answer.java with loaddatabase() but close it in databasehelper.java with myDbHelper.close();

Comment: "Because I load the database in my answer.java with loaddatabase() but close it in databasehelper.java with myDbHelper.close();" I tend to close the database in a matching process everywhere I open it. Generally, if I open a database in `onResume()` I close it in `onPause()`, if I open it in one method I close it in that same method. This way I don't have to guess or look at a different class to see if I closed it or not. This approach makes maintainance easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much an answer as a hack.  But you could try putting a database close in the in your database helper class's openDatabase method.  Something like the following might work.

```
    if (this.db.isOpen()) {
       this.db.close();
    }
```

Comment: you mean before opening a new one?

Comment: Yes, check if its open (and not null).  If it is open, close it then re-open.